# Tooltip: Json content load

Tags: jquery, json, tooltip

I want to show a tooltip with content loaded from a json file. I am using the [tooltipsy](https://github.com/briancray/tooltipsy) plugin.

The element where the tooltip must show info about is given an REL with number.

```
<span class="question hastip" rel="1">
```

This number will represent the elements in the json object

```
{
"users" : [ 
    {
        "name"   : "John",
        "functie" : "Frontend webdev"
    },
    {
        "name"   : "Doe", 
        "functie" : "backend webdev"
    }
]
```

}

This is my code I call onready:

```
    $('.hastip').tooltipsy({
    showEvent: 'click',
    hideEvent: 'click',

    content: function ($el, $tip) {
        var $el = $(this);
        var active_tooltip = $el.attr('rel');

        $.getJSON('/Scripts/test.js', function (data) {

            $tip.html(function() {
              var title = data.users[active_tooltip].name;
              var mtext = data.users[active_tooltip].functie;
              return '<div>' + title + mtext +  '</div>';
            });
        });
        return 'Fallback content';
    },

});
```

obviously I am not able to fix it, any help? I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwavg/S97Sp/)

Comment: are you gettin any errors?? or you just gettin only one value in the tooltip??

Comment: Sorry edit my post (data.users[active_tooltip].name). I think the fault lies in the `var active_tooltip = $el.attr('rel');` In the console I see $el.attr('0') but then I step over it is undefined

Comment: try console.log(active_tooltip) and see if u get the rel value or not?? let me know

Comment: Hi, its undefined.. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwavg/S97Sp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.....
content: function ($el, $tip) {
   // var $el = $(this); //no need ,$el is given by the $el in content options.
    var active_tooltip = $el.attr('rel');

    $.getJSON('/Scripts/test.js', function (data) {

        $tip.html(function() {
          var title = data.users[active_tooltip].name;
          var mtext = data.users[active_tooltip].functie;
          return '<div>' + title + mtext +  '</div>';
        });
    });
    return 'Fallback content';
},
....
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/S97Sp/4/) ..check the console...